# How to wipe OS only

Tags: operating-systems, wipe

I'd like to wipe my corrupted OS entirely before installing a new. I've found your answer how to do it along with the full disk, but I'd like to keep the other partitions (data).

How to wipe one partition, viz. C:\ only? I mean wipe totally, not Windows' own Reset only.

Comment: If your system is on a separate partition and not together with the data you can only format the partition containing the OS. Otherwise, if you don't, setup a [Linux Live CD](https://livecdlist.com/) and copy your data to a external drive or another partition on your drive.

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to format the partition in question, and re-install windows on that. If all your data is on other partitions, leave those alone and you're good.

As far as I can remember, Windows asks you which partitions you want to re-format during an install. The are also several live CDs with graphical tools that will let you edit and reformat partitions.

Are most of your programs also installed on `C:`, or are they somewhere else? Once Windows is installed, all of the programs also have to be re-installed.

In the Windows default configuration, many programs will also have been saving their data to `C:`, in your own personal `User` folder. You might want to play safe and copy that out to another partition before you proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I have not installed windows recently, but AFAICR there was an option to format the partition you are installing on during the insalation. Boot from a DVD with Windows installation disk and you should be able to do it.